# Convert Rescore JSON Query to Java

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch

I'm using the elasticsearch LTR plugin in my cluster and I'm having a tough time converting the following JSON rescore query to Java code. I can't seem to find the right objects in the elasticsearch java client to do it.

Here is my query:

```
"rescore": {
      "query": {
        "rescore_query": {
          "sltr": {
            "params": {
              "keywords": "soccer cleats"
            },
            "model": "model"
          }
        },
        "query_weight": 1,
        "rescore_query_weight": 100
      },
      "window_size": 500
    },
```

I've tried using `QueryRescorerBuilder queryRescorerBuilder = QueryBuilders.rescoreQuery()` like I do to build my other queries but that rescoreQuery() doesn't seem to be part of the java client.

What am I missing?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [wrapper query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wrapper-query.html)

```
String customQuery = String.format("{ \"sltr\": { \"params\": { \"keywords\": \"%s\" }, \"model\": \"%s\" } }", "soccer cleats", "model");

WrapperQueryBuilder wrapperQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.wrapperQuery(customQuery);

QueryRescorerBuilder queryRescorerBuilder = new QueryRescorerBuilder(wrapperQueryBuilder);
queryRescorerBuilder.setQueryWeight(1);
queryRescorerBuilder.setRescoreQueryWeight(100);
queryRescorerBuilder.windowSize(500);

SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery());
searchSourceBuilder.addRescorer(queryRescorerBuilder);

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
searchRequest.indices("MY_INDEX");

System.out.println(searchRequest.toString());
```

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  },
  "rescore": [
    {
      "window_size": 500,
      "query": {
        "rescore_query": {
          "wrapper": {
            "query": "eyAic2x0ciI6IHsgInBhcmFtcyI6IHsgImtleXdvcmRzIjogInNvY2NlciBjbGVhdHMiIH0sICJtb2RlbCI6ICJtb2RlbCIgfSB9"
          }
        },
        "query_weight": 1.0,
        "rescore_query_weight": 100.0,
        "score_mode": "total"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I don't think its a right approach as this is hardcoding the query, what If I need to change some values in my query?

Comment: @es-enthu         String customQuery = String.format("{ \"sltr\": { \"params\": { \"keywords\": \"%s\" }, \"model\": \"%s\" } }", "soccer cleats", "model");

Comment: yeah looks much better now